# "The default heap size is 1 MB". How come can I malloc() more then, do I misunderstand the word 'heap'?

Tags: windows, linker, heap-memory, portable-executable, stack-memory

In Microsoft Visual C++, I needed more stack space. So I went into the linker properties and raised it. But then I noticed another property: **"Heap Reserve Size"** (Linker Option: /HEAP) with the Note: "The default heap size is 1 MB".

How come I can malloc 50MB "*on the heap*" with a heap size of 1MB?

If I do the same with the stack, I get an out of stack space exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come I can malloc 50MB "on the heap" with a heap size of 1MB?
>
> If I do the same with the stack, I get an out of stack space
>   exception.

That's because the heap can grow whereas the stack is fixed. `1MB` is just the initial size of the heap.